# SSL_accept fails on non-blocking socket stream

Tags: c++, openssl, winsock

Guess, I have a simple client-server application.
Non-blocking mode is enabled to implement manual connection timeouts.

SSL_accept always returns -1.
The error string returned by `SSL_get_error` → `ERR_get_string` is:

```
    error:00000001:lib(0):func(0):reason(1)
```

**UPDATE**
Probably, it's about the SSL api usage.
Could anyone clarify, what is the proper sequence of actions?
That's what I do:

For client:

1. create socket (`::socket`)
2. switch to non-blocking mode (`::ioctlsocket`)
3. connect to the server (`::connect`)
4. wait until write operation is finished (`::select`)
5. initialize SSL socket; start handshake (`::SSL_connect`)
6. loop processing `SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ` and `SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ` (`::select`)

For server:

1. create socket (`::socket`)
2. `::bind`
3. `::listen`
4. switch to non-blocking mode (`::ioctlsocket`)
5. wait until a new connection is accepted (`::select`)
6. accept a client (`::accept`)
7. initialize SSL socket; start handshake (`::SSL_accept`)
8. loop processing `SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ` and `SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ` (`::select`)

Comment: You need to reset `tv` before every `select().` You aren't actually enforcing any timeout during the `SSL_accept()` phase, so you can do that part in blocking mode.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. This code is placed in several functions, so I just missed a bit. It's very simplified, therefore you can't get the reason I use non-blocking sockets. I want to implement it this way just because I need to wake up time-to-time, to check something. So, If I did it in the blocking mode, there would be the only way to interrupt listening - close socket. But I don't need to close connection. That's why I'm trying to listen via non-blocking sockets.

Comment: Maybe you just haven't cleared the thread's error stack prior to calling `SSL_accept` and are seeing leftover garbage from previous operations. It would help a lot to see the real code.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I've got this error string while unwinding error stack. `error:1408A0C1:SSL routines:ssl3_get_client_hello:no shared cipher`

Comment: @MAKAKOKO There you go. That's the problem.

Comment: I've initialized SSL_CTX with the certificates created by [this](http://dst.lbl.gov/~boverhof/openssl_certs.html) tutorial. And I've got an error: `error:14089086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_client_certificate:certificate verify failed`